# Jquery Click not working in IBM Mobile first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

Below is the code i have added in main.js file

```
 $(function(){
    $(".menuHorizontal div").click(function(){
       console.log('hi');

    });
});
```

Below is my html DOM structure

```
    <div class="menuHorizontal">
      <div class="yellow-borBottom">All</div>
      <div>Elevators</div>
      <div>Escalators</div>
      <div>Walkways</div>
  </div>
```

my jquery click function wont works, no event on click. not even it shows error in console. plz help me to resolve this

I have added a seperate Jquery file too but still wont works

Comment: Looks like you have broken HTML. The `<div class="menuHorizontal">` must be closed with `</div>`

Comment: its closed in my actual code ... i forgot to paste it here

Comment: If you try the same code outside IBM MobileFirst project , does it work? May be a pure cordova application or html?

Comment: Put a console.log in the ready function and see if it fires. If not you know it's not hitting there and thus not binding the event. Also check your spelling of `menuHorizontal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you have this scoped attaches an event to all div's contained within a div assigned class `menuHorizontal`. In the code that you posted, there are none of these!

```
<div class="menuHorizontal">mush be close with</div> // No divs inside here!
```

You closed the div with class menuHorizontal too soon. Two options below. The former will also attach the event to the "mush be close with" text, while the latter will not.

```
<div class="menuHorizontal">
    <div>mush be close with</div>
    <div class="yellow-borBottom">All</div>
    <div>Elevators</div>
    <div>Escalators</div>
    <div>Walkways</div>
</div>

<div class="menuHorizontal">>mush be close with
    <div class="yellow-borBottom">All</div>
    <div>Elevators</div>
    <div>Escalators</div>
    <div>Walkways</div>
</div>
```

Were you trying to scope like this, which attaches the event to div's with class menuHorizontal?

```
$("div.menuHorizontal").click(function(){
   console.log('hi');
```

You might also want to change your scope to the higher level div, like so. Google `event bubbling` for more info

```
$(".menuHorizontal").click(function(){
   console.log('hi');
```

Also, consider using jQuery .on(), as follows. It's a little more current, and generally more flexible.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(function(){
    $(".menuHorizontal div").on('click', function(){
       console.log('hi');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menuHorizontal div").click(function(){
   console.log('hi');
});
```

This does not work because in your HTML `<div class="menuHorizontal">mush be close with</div>` you dont have a div inside of the div `.menuHorizontal` so the event is not binded on any div ( as it doesn't exist). So you can do as below.

Change your HTML to

```
<div class="menuHorizontal">mush be close with
    <div class="yellow-borBottom">All</div>
    <div>Elevators</div>
    <div>Escalators</div>
    <div>Walkways</div>
</div>
```

And the existing jquery must work fine.

And here is [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/6fawLabt/1/)

Comment: i tried all of the possibilites but i get error asUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1210:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM1209:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM1209:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1209:664
2main.js:80 undefined

Comment: @user3541560 did you even check my Fiddle?? https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/6fawLabt/1/ it works here. check what is wrong in your side. Put all your scripts in document ready event